# why with click on one label tag, two label tags selected?

Tags: jquery, click, label

I have a label tag with display equal block. when I click on one label tag, two label tag would show on console.

jQuery Code:

```
var lbl = $("label")
lbl.on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this);
  console.log(target);
})
```

HTML Code:

```
<label class="clearfix">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <img class="filter_unchecked" src="img/svg/button.svg" alt="">
  <img class="filter_checked" src="img/svg/checkmark.svg" alt="">
  <span>تک</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of checkbox change event is also fired at the same time, you should prevent default action as well.

The click event is first handled by the label and is then passed on to the checkbox.

However while this prevents event bubbling it also has the undesirable side effect of preventing the checkbox from changing state. So you'll need to prevent default action as well.

```
lbl.on("click", function(e) {
  //e.stopPropagation(); // you don't need this by the way
  e.preventDefault(); //try adding this
  var target = $(this);
  console.log(target);
})
```